# M1 Mac g++ use GMP Library error Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 "__ZlsRSoPK12__mpz_struct"

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, gmp

I use `gcc` with brew on my M1 Mac, But these code can run successfully with `clang`, but can not linked with `g++`(Homebrew).

```bash
$ g++-12 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++-12
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin21/12/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-apple-darwin21
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc --libdir=/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current --disable-nls --enable-checking=release --with-gcc-major-version-only --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-12 --with-gmp=/opt/homebrew/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/opt/homebrew/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/opt/homebrew/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/opt/homebrew/opt/isl --with-zstd=/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 12.2.0' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --with-system-zlib --build=aarch64-apple-darwin21 --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0)
```

And My code for GMP:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "gmp.h"
#include "gmpxx.h"

using namespace std;
int main() { // Declare two arbitrary-precision integers
    mpz_t x, y;

    // Initialize the integers
    mpz_init(x);
    mpz_init(y);

    // Set the value of x to 1234567890
    mpz_set_str(x, "1234567890", 10);

    // Set the value of y to 9876543210
    mpz_set_str(y, "9876543210", 10);

    // Declare a third arbitrary-precision integer to store the result
    mpz_t result;
    mpz_init(result);

    // Perform the multiplication
    mpz_mul(result, x, y);

    // Print the result
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;

    // Clear the variables to free memory
    mpz_clear(x);
    mpz_clear(y);
    mpz_clear(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```bash
$ g++-12 gmp_test.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__ZlsRSoPK12__mpz_struct", referenced from:
      __Z2t1v in cceShKq0.o
      __ZlsIA1_12__mpz_struct17__gmp_binary_exprI10__gmp_exprIS1_S1_ES4_23__gmp_binary_multipliesEERSoS7_RKS3_IT_T0_E in cceShKq0.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can run the above code with both `llvm clang`(with brew) and `/usr/bin/clang`(with xcode), but cannot run with g++, and I don't not why!

Comment: Are you using the same standard library in all cases? libc++ and libstdc++ are not compatible.

Comment: GCC might be picking his own GMP

Comment: Maybe gcc(brew) can not found its GMP?